# why should i downcast the context as an instance of the interface?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-context, downcast

I just started to learn the fragment API on Android.
I want just to send a message back to my containing activity(I did it). Now I want to clear a misunderstanding about downcasting.

Here is my fragment:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

private EditText textFirstName, textLastName, textAge;
private FragmentListener mListener;

public DetailFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    if (!(context instanceof FragmentListener)) throw new AssertionError();
    mListener = (FragmentListener) context;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);

    textFirstName = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textFirstName);
    textLastName = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textLastName);
    textAge = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textAge);

    Button doneButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.done_button);
    doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            done();
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}

private void done() {
    if (mListener == null) {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }

    String firstName = textFirstName.getText().toString();
    String lastName = textLastName.getText().toString();
    int age = Integer.valueOf(textAge.getText().toString());

    mListener.onFragmentFinish(firstName, lastName, age);
}

public interface FragmentListener {
    void onFragmentFinish(String firstName, String lastName, int age);
}

}
```

I don't understand the downcasting here:

```
mListener = (FragmentListener) context;
```

How Context class relate to my FragmentListener interface?

I find this is contradictory to my knowledge about downcasting(Downcasting is casting to a subtype, downward to the inheritance tree.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two types, `Context` and `FragmentListener` are unrelated. However, a subclass of `Context` might implement the `FragmentListener` interface. Your `onAttach()` method checks that this is, in fact, what's happening and does the downcast so the `FragmentListener` functionality is available through the `mListener` member field.

Any `Context` (most likely an `Activity`) that attaches an instance of `DetailFragment` will need to implement `DetailFragment.FragmentListener` to avoid an `AssertionError` at run time.